# Env node\r: No such file or directory with 3dio-js

Tags: gulp, archilogic

Does anyone else have issues running 3dio-js locally with gulp?

When trying to run [3dio-js](https://github.com/archilogic-com/3dio-js) locally (`npm run dev-browser`), I get the following error:

Env node\r: No such file or directory

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, it seems to be an issue [with gulp](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/1758#issuecomment-303724551) and DOS-line endings.

`vi /3dio-js/node-modules/.bin/gulp`

`:set ff=unix`
`:wq!`

and then run it again

`npm run dev-browser`